# URI Routing In Codigniter Without Htaccess

Tags: php, uri, redirect, codeigniter-2

This is my url of site:

```
xxx.myserver.net
```

In this site i want to routing the controller that means when i linkthis type url :

```
xxx.myserver.net/aaaaa
```

I want to redirect it into the controller which i desired taht means i want to redirect into :

```
xxx.myserver.net/index.php/controller-name/funation-name/aaaaa
```

I want to done this without using htaccess method only by using codeigniter uri routing method.

When i try to do this i get an error message :

```
Not Found

The requested URL  not found on this server.
```

This is the code i gave in the routes.php page:

```
$route['/(:any)'] = "xxx.myserver.net/index.php/controller-name/funation-name/$1";
```

What is the problem in my code?

How can i do this ?

Comment: You can't do this without `.htaccess`, you are confusing the route config file with what `.htaccess` does. The route config file only routes to CONTROLLERS, not actual files on your server (which is what htaccess is doing).

Comment: you mean route config file is only for routing controllers not for server pathing?

Comment: correct, you only route parameters to controllers, not to files or anything of the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that without using an `.htaccess` file.  From a high level, the purpose of the `.htaccess` file is to route all requests to your domain through the CodeIgniter front controller, the `index.php` file in your root directory.  Here is the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) that explains how creating the `.htaccess` file and removing `index.php` from the URL works.  To paraphrase, it states how arbitrary requests are treated as requests for the `index.php` file.

When you make a request to `xxx.myserver.net/aaaaa` the web server is searching for the resource `aaaaa` in your root.  The request isn't even being processed by CodeIgniter.  Since you have no resource titled `aaaaa` you are receiving an error.

To use CodeIgniter without an `.htaccess` file you'll need to pass each request through `index.php`.  For example:

`xxx.myserver.net/index.php/aaaaa`

Then you could create your route like this:

`$route['(:any)'] = 'controller_name/function_name/$1';`

Comment: i set like this $route['(:any)'] = 'controller_name/function_name/$1'; And took the above got this error 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.